# php gd font size different from photoshop

Tags: php, gd, photoshop

I'm trying to reproduce a sample photoshop file with gd (same thing, except that text is dynamic). However I'm facing an unexpected issue.

For instance in photoshop I have a text "Fallen Angel" with font Optima 9.46pt 
I'm doing with gd :

```
imagefttext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $fontPath, $text);
```

$fontPath is Optima.ttf (in same directory as the php script) and $fontSize is 9.46

what I have on photoshop psd : http://data.imagup.com/10/1175958620.png

what I have on php gd : http://data.imagup.com/12/1175958598.png

I don't understand the difference, both gd and photoshop are working with pt unit and the same font

Comment: Point sizes are relative to the resolution of the image. 9.46 pt font in a 72 ppi image is going to be different than a 112 ppi image.

Comment: so how should I calculate size for my fonts ?

Comment: This is an interesting question. It appears that internally the conversion is based on 96 ppi. There seems to be no way to get or change this. But you can use 96 ppi to calculate the correct point size for you font.